SimPy Simulation: How to Ensure Single Container Unloading and Sequential Transport in a Container Terminal?
I'm working on a SimPy simulation for a container terminal where vessels arrive, berth, and unload containers using cranes, followed by transport using trucks. Problem Statement_pt1 ,Problem statement_pt2
I need to ensure that:

Only one container is unloaded at a time per crane.
Untill empty trucks are available , the crane should continue its unloading process independent of whether the prior trucks have completed their transfer.
If no truck is available then the crane needs to wait till it can start unloading containers.

simulation.py
import simpy
from vessel import Vessel
from config import *
import random

class Simulation:
    def __init__(self, simulation_time):
        self.env = simpy.Environment()
        self.simulation_time = simulation_time
        self.berth_resource = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity=NUM_BERTHS)
        self.crane_resource = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity=NUM_CRANES)
        self.truck_resource = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity=NUM_TRUCKS)
        
    def generate_vessels(self):
        vessel_id = 1
        while True:
            yield self.env.timeout(random.expovariate(1 / (AVERAGE_INTERARRIVAL_TIME * 60)))  # time between arrivals
            vessel = Vessel(self.env, vessel_id, self.berth_resource, self.crane_resource, self.truck_resource)
            print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Vessel {vessel_id} arrives.")
            self.env.process(vessel.process())
            vessel_id += 1
            print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Number of vessels waiting for berths: {len(self.berth_resource.queue)}")
            print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Number of vessels currently being served at berths: {self.berth_resource.count}")
            print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Number of cranes currently being used: {self.crane_resource.count}")
            print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Number of trucks currently being used: {self.truck_resource.count}")
            
    def run(self):
        """Run the simulation"""
        self.env.process(self.generate_vessels())
        self.env.run(until=self.simulation_time)

vessel.py


import random
import simpy
from config import NUM_CONTAINERS, AVERAGE_INTERARRIVAL_TIME, CRANE_LIFT_TIME, TRUCK_CYCLE_TIME

class Vessel:
    def __init__(self, env, id, berth_resource, crane_resource, truck_resource):
        self.env = env
        self.id = id
        self.containers = NUM_CONTAINERS
        self.berth_resource = berth_resource
        self.crane_resource = crane_resource
        self.truck_resource = truck_resource
        self.container_queue = simpy.Store(env)  # Queue to hold unloaded containers

    def berth(self):
        """Simulate vessel berthing"""
        with self.berth_resource.request() as request:
            yield request
            print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Vessel {self.id} starts berthing.")
            print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Vessel {self.id} finished berthing.")
            yield self.env.process(self.unload())

    

    
    def unload_container(self, container_id):
        """Simulate unloading a single container"""
        print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Vessel {self.id} requests crane for container {container_id + 1}.")
        with self.crane_resource.request() as crane_request:
            yield crane_request
            print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Quay crane starts unloading container {container_id + 1} from vessel {self.id}.")
            yield self.env.timeout(CRANE_LIFT_TIME)  # Crane time to unload one container
            print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Quay crane finished unloading container {container_id + 1} from vessel {self.id}.")
            yield self.container_queue.put(container_id)  # Add the unloaded container to the queue
            # Start the transport process for this container after unloading
            self.env.process(self.transport_container(container_id))

    def transport_container(self, container_id):
        """Simulate the transport of a container by a truck"""
        print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Vessel {self.id} requests truck for container {container_id + 1}.")
        with self.truck_resource.request() as truck_request:
            yield truck_request
            print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Truck starts transporting container {container_id + 1} from vessel {self.id}.")
            yield self.env.timeout(TRUCK_CYCLE_TIME)  # Truck time to transport the container
            print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Truck finished transporting container {container_id + 1} from vessel {self.id}.")

    def unload(self):
        """Unload all containers from the vessel"""
        unload_processes = [self.env.process(self.unload_container(i)) for i in range(self.containers)]
        for process in unload_processes:
            yield process  # Wait for all unload processes to finish
        print(f"Time {self.env.now}: Vessel {self.id} has been fully unloaded and leaves the berth.")

    
    def process(self):
        """Process the entire sequence of arrival, berthing, and unloading"""
        yield self.env.process(self.berth())
        

Output:
Enter the number of hours to run the simulation: 3
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 arrives.
Time 104.4311467616123: Number of vessels waiting for berths: 0
Time 104.4311467616123: Number of vessels currently being served at berths: 0
Time 104.4311467616123: Number of cranes currently being used: 0
Time 104.4311467616123: Number of trucks currently being used: 0
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 starts berthing.
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 finished berthing.
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests crane for container 1.
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests crane for container 2.
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests crane for container 3.
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests crane for container 4.
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests crane for container 5.
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests crane for container 6.
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests crane for container 7.
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests crane for container 8.
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests crane for container 9.
Time 104.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests crane for container 10.
Time 104.4311467616123: Quay crane starts unloading container 1 from vessel 1.
Time 104.4311467616123: Quay crane starts unloading container 2 from vessel 1.
Time 107.4311467616123: Quay crane finished unloading container 1 from vessel 1.
Time 107.4311467616123: Quay crane finished unloading container 2 from vessel 1.
Time 107.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests truck for container 1.
Time 107.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests truck for container 2.
Time 107.4311467616123: Truck starts transporting container 1 from vessel 1.
Time 107.4311467616123: Truck starts transporting container 2 from vessel 1.
Time 107.4311467616123: Quay crane starts unloading container 3 from vessel 1.
Time 107.4311467616123: Quay crane starts unloading container 4 from vessel 1.
Time 110.4311467616123: Quay crane finished unloading container 3 from vessel 1.
Time 110.4311467616123: Quay crane finished unloading container 4 from vessel 1.
Time 110.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests truck for container 3.
Time 110.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests truck for container 4.
Time 110.4311467616123: Truck starts transporting container 3 from vessel 1.
Time 110.4311467616123: Quay crane starts unloading container 5 from vessel 1.
Time 110.4311467616123: Quay crane starts unloading container 6 from vessel 1.
Time 113.4311467616123: Truck finished transporting container 1 from vessel 1.
Time 113.4311467616123: Truck finished transporting container 2 from vessel 1.
Time 113.4311467616123: Quay crane finished unloading container 5 from vessel 1.
Time 113.4311467616123: Quay crane finished unloading container 6 from vessel 1.
Time 113.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests truck for container 5.
Time 113.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests truck for container 6.
Time 113.4311467616123: Truck starts transporting container 4 from vessel 1.
Time 113.4311467616123: Truck starts transporting container 5 from vessel 1.
Time 113.4311467616123: Quay crane starts unloading container 7 from vessel 1.
Time 113.4311467616123: Quay crane starts unloading container 8 from vessel 1.
Time 116.4311467616123: Truck finished transporting container 3 from vessel 1.
Time 116.4311467616123: Quay crane finished unloading container 7 from vessel 1.
Time 116.4311467616123: Quay crane finished unloading container 8 from vessel 1.
Time 116.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests truck for container 7.
Time 116.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests truck for container 8.
Time 116.4311467616123: Truck starts transporting container 6 from vessel 1.
Time 116.4311467616123: Quay crane starts unloading container 9 from vessel 1.
Time 116.4311467616123: Quay crane starts unloading container 10 from vessel 1.
Time 119.4311467616123: Truck finished transporting container 4 from vessel 1.
Time 119.4311467616123: Truck finished transporting container 5 from vessel 1.
Time 119.4311467616123: Quay crane finished unloading container 9 from vessel 1.
Time 119.4311467616123: Quay crane finished unloading container 10 from vessel 1.
Time 119.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests truck for container 9.
Time 119.4311467616123: Vessel 1 requests truck for container 10.
Time 119.4311467616123: Truck starts transporting container 7 from vessel 1.
Time 119.4311467616123: Truck starts transporting container 8 from vessel 1.
Time 119.4311467616123: Vessel 1 has been fully unloaded and leaves the berth.
Time 122.4311467616123: Truck finished transporting container 6 from vessel 1.
Time 122.4311467616123: Truck starts transporting container 9 from vessel 1.
Time 125.4311467616123: Truck finished transporting container 7 from vessel 1.
Time 125.4311467616123: Truck finished transporting container 8 from vessel 1.
Time 125.4311467616123: Truck starts transporting container 10 from vessel 1.
Time 128.4311467616123: Truck finished transporting container 9 from vessel 1.
Time 131.4311467616123: Truck finished transporting container 10 from vessel 1.

Issue:
I am unable to achieve both the requirements 1 and 2. Initially I didn't think of cranes unloading simultaneously while trucks are transfering and I was able to run the simulation under that restriction.
The mentioned implementation is able to run the process of unloading and transfer independently but for I am unable to fix the issue with two containers being able to use both the cranes or trucks simultaneously(as highlighted in the output)
What I've Tried:
Sequentially processing container unloading and transport but still facing issues with simultaneous unloading.
Any guidance or suggestions on how to correct this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Desired Output:
Enter the number of hours to run the simulation: 3
Time 1: Vessel 1 starts berthing.
Time 1: Vessel 1 finished berthing.
Time 1: Quay crane starts unloading container 1 from vessel 1.
Time 4: Quay crane finished unloading container 1 from vessel 1.
Time 4: Truck starts transporting container 1 from vessel 1.
Time 4: Quay crane starts unloading container 2 from vessel 1.
Time 7: Quay crane finished unloading container 2 from vessel 1.
Time 7: Quay crane starts unloading container 3 from vessel 1.
Time 7: Truck starts transporting container 2 from vessel 1.
Time 7: Quay crane finished unloading container 2 from vessel 1.
Time 7:Vessel 2 starts berthing.
Time 7: Vessel 2 finished berthing.
.
.
.


You have a really good start but I think I see the issue
unload_processes = [self.env.process(self.unload_container(i)) for i in range(self.containers)]

When you create these processes, you are also starting these processes.
The yield in the loop does not start the process, it only checks if the process has finished, and if the process has not finished, then it will wait till the process has finished before doing the next iteration of the loop.
try something like:
for i in range(self.containers):
    yield self.env.process(self.unload_container(i)) # Wait for each container to be unloaded

where you are creating (and starting) each process one at a time, and waiting for that process to finish before creating (and starting) the next one.
This may not be the only issue though...

should the containers be seizing cranes, or should the cranes be seizing the containers?

So I did make the change now and it is working fine but I have encountered a new issue ,the crane unloading process must halt/wait if no free truck resource is available and continue when at least one is available but when i manually checked the output I noticed the cranes have no delay/wait in time at all at any instace. I am skeptical that maybe the truck resourcse is not getting allocated properly.

You are right, your crane is not waiting for the truck to arrive.  In your unload_container process, you need to request a truck, and yield to the request (no with block).  After the yield, then you call your transport_container process and pass in the request.  In transport_container you will need to remove the with block and just do a release resource with the passed in request at the end.  That is how the answer with the code is doing it and I suspect why the requirements mention you can request resources without a with block

I need a suggestion regarding how should I deal with the relationship between truck and cranes. So after reading the problem statement I thought I should not make a container hold on to a free truck resource till its unloading is done as maybe another container can use the truck before it. But now this might lead to race conditions.The problem statement doesn't explicitly allow us to hold on to a truck.

look at my code and the unload_ship process
The truck process needs to be broken down in two parts: getting the truck, and the truck moving the container to the yard
The crane grabs a truck, and waits / yields to the request util a truck is acquired.  The crane dose not release the truck.  The filled truck request is passed to a truck move process which the crane does not yield to.  This truck move process releases the truck once the container is delivered to the yard.

I took a stab as solving the sim problem and here is my take.
The one embellishment I added was the option for the berth use more then one crain at a time.
Also, when a berth seizes a crane it keeps the crane until the ship is unloaded, then it releases it.
"""
Simulates a container shipping terminal for unloading ships

When a ship seizes a crane, the crane stays with the ship
until the ship is unloaded.

Ships can seize more then one crane up to a max

programmer Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
import random

class ID_Objects():
    """
    A simpe class
    The purpose of the class is to insure
    each container has a unque ID
    """

    next_id = 1

    def __init__(self):
        """
        create a object with a unique id
        """

        self.id = self.__class__.next_id
        self.__class__.next_id += 1


class Ship_Container(ID_Objects):
    """
    Containers with a unique set of ids
    """
    pass

class Vessel(ID_Objects):
    """
    The ship to be unloaded
    Has a list of containers to be unloaded
    """

    def __init__(self, containers:int):
        """
        Create the ship and load with containers
        """

        ID_Objects.__init__(self)

        self.container_list = [Ship_Container() for _ in range(containers)]

class Terminal():
    """
    The shipping terminal that unload ships as they arrive

    """

    def __init__(self, env, births:int, cranes:int, trucks:int, cranes_per_birth:int=1):
        self.env = env          # simulation environment var
        self.births = births    # The number of ship births
        self.cranes = cranes    # cranes for unloading ships
        self.trucks = trucks    # trucks to move contains to storage
        self.cranes_per_birth = cranes_per_birth # max number of cranes a birth can use at one time


        # convert counts to resourc pools (res)
        self.birth_res = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity=self.births)
        self.crane_res = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity=self.cranes)
        self.truck_res = simpy.Resource(self.env, capacity=self.trucks)

    def ship_arrives(self, ship):
        """
        Ship arrives at the terminal
        Starts the chain of processes to dock, unload, and depart a ship
        """

        print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}: ship {ship.id} has arrived at port')

        # wait and get a birth
        with self.birth_res.request() as b_req:
            yield b_req

            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}: ship {ship.id} has a birth')

            # get cranes and start unloading ship

            unload_done_event = self.env.event()
            # when more then one crane is beng requested
            # this event is used to handel the speical case when the
            # fist sezied crane finishes unloading a ship
            # before the second request gets filled (cancel unneded second request)

            cranes= [self.env.process(self.unload_ship(ship, unload_done_event))
                        for _ in range(self.cranes_per_birth)
            ]

            # wait for all the cranes to finish
            yield self.env.all_of(cranes)
        
        print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}: ship {ship.id} has a left its birth')

    def unload_ship(self, ship:Vessel, unload_done_event:simpy.Event):
        """
        get a crane and unload the ship
        crian is release when ship is unloaded
        """

        with self.crane_res.request() as c_req:

            print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}: ship {ship.id} has requested a crane')
            yield self.env.any_of([c_req, unload_done_event])

            # did we get a crane or did first crane finish the job before this request was filled
            if unload_done_event.triggered:
                # unload is done, no crane is needed
                # the with block will cancel the unfulfilled request
                 print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}: ship {ship.id} crane request canceled')
            else:
                # have a crane, use it to unload
                print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}: ship {ship.id} has seized a crane')

                while len(ship.container_list) > 0:
                    # get a container
                    cont = ship.container_list.pop()
                    yield self.env.timeout(3)

                    # get and send truck
                    # not using a with block becaue 
                    # another process will release the truck
                    t_req = self.truck_res.request()

                    print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}: continer {cont.id} from ship {ship.id} is waiting for a truck')
                    
                    yield t_req
                    
                    print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}: continer {cont.id} from ship {ship.id} has seized a truck')
                    
                    # note no yield here
                    # do not want the crane to wait for the truck to get back
                    # but to immediatly start getting next container
                    self.env.process(self.stash_container(cont, t_req))

                print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}: ship {ship.id} has released crane')

                # cancels any open crane requests
                if not unload_done_event.triggered:
                    unload_done_event.succeed()



    def stash_container(self, cont, t_req):
        """
        Uses the seized truck to move a container to the yard.
        The seized truck is relased at the end of the process
        """  

        print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}: continer {cont.id} is being taken to the yard')

        yield self.env.timeout(6)

        print(f'{self.env.now:.2f}: continer {cont.id} has been taken to the yard, release truck')

        # release truck seized in calling process
        yield self.truck_res.release(t_req)


def gen_ships(env:simpy.Environment, terminal:Terminal):
    """
    Generate the arrialve of ships and notifies the terminal it has
    has arrived and waiting for a birth
    """

    while True:
        yield env.timeout(random.expovariate(1.0/(5*60))) # ave of 5 hours

        # no yield here, not waiting for ship to get unloaded
        # before starting next arriavl loop
        env.process(terminal.ship_arrives(Vessel(150)))


def sim():
    """
    init and run the simulation
    """
    print("starting simulation")

    env = simpy.Environment()
    terminal = Terminal(env, 
                        births=2, 
                        cranes=2, 
                        trucks=3, 
                        cranes_per_birth=1
                        )
    
    env.process(gen_ships(env,terminal))

    env.run(50*60) # run for 50 hours

    print(f"{env.now:.2f} simulation has finished")


if __name__ == '__main__':
   
   sim()

    


Thanks for the help ! The original problem statement atually allows a vessel to use only one crane till all the containers are unloaded.

setting the cranes_per_birth = 1 will enforce that requirement

Will try it . Also I just noticed were all the 3 responses given by you ? What's the order to read them :)

yes all three are me

I went through your code . Let me know if I am right , when the unloading of a container is done but no truck resource is available ,the crane will not wait before unloading the next container. But practically shouldn't the crane wait as in this scenario the container is hanging by the crane so untill this container is kept on a truck there is no way it can move to next container.

yield t_req    If there is no truck available, the crane will wait until a truck is available.    Once the crane has a truck, it sends the truck to the yard self.env.process(self.stash_container(cont, t_req))  but since there is not yield here the crane does not wait for the truck to complete its trip.  It then loops to get the next container.  Also note that this loop does not release the truck, the stash_container process does that.

This is a good start
The part you are missing is each birth can have only one crane.
you need to structure you code so that:
after the ship gets a berth
The ship grabs a crane (not the container)
while the ship has the crane loop over each container
delay the lift time
grab a truck
start the truck process (no yield here)
loop to next container.
note the truck process will need to release the truck
